# indirect proof with even and odd numbers

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following through an indirect proof-

if $m+n$ is even, then $m$ and $n$ are even or $m$ and $n$ are odd.

in order to do so I have to negate both parts of the statement and prove it from the end to the beginning.

my restatement is-

if $m$ is odd and $n$ is even or $m$ is even and $n$ is odd, then $m+n$ is odd.

- I would like to know if my restatement is correct and actually the negated from of the above
- Does one have to do something special with the "or" at the middle of the statement, or it should be leaved untouched as is?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are correct. But I would like you to note that since the operation  $+$ is commutative, you only need to consider the case where  $m $ is odd and $n $ is even. You can write "WLOG" as usual to prove your line.

Comment: This is a proof by contrapositive ($P \to Q$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot Q\to\lnot P$). You could make  it slightly shorter by observing the assertion is symmetric in $m$ and $n$, so you may say ‘if one of$m,n$ is odd, say $m$, …’

Comment: "is my restatement the correct negated form of the above ?" NO

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so would you write its correct form?

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is correct but technically not the negation of the original statement.

The negation of

"$m$ and $n$ are even or $m$ and $n$ are odd"

is

"(at least) one of $m,n$ is odd and (at least) one of $m,n$ is even".

In fact, the only options for *at least* are *exactly*, making one of the two conditions redundant. In practice you could render this by

"$m,n$ have different parities".